# Информация о ПК силами php

Tags: php, cookie, авторизация

Здравствуйте.
Есть механизм по работе с галкой "Запомнить меня", если юзер устанавливает галку, то в куку записывается информация: id-хеш, также инфа пишется в базу. При заходе на сайт, идет проверка на существовании куки, если она есть оттуда берется информация, ищется в базе указанный id юзера, затем сравнивается его хеши для запоминалок и хеш из куки и при положительной проверки идет авторизация клиента.
Но есть проблема - если куку украсть и создать на другом компе куку с таким же названием и содержимым, то без труда происходит авторизация.
Вопрос - как можно добавить информацию о ПК юзера для бОльшей гарантии, что это именно он, а не злоумышленник. IP брать думаю не имеет смысла.
Подобную инфу я вижу если зайти на сайт 2ip.ru, каким способом они выводят инфу о моем ПК?
Выслушаю другие варианты реализации функции "Запомнить меня".
Спасибо.
**PS**: извиняюсь перед модераторами если неточно указал тему вопроса.

Comment: `IP`как раз имеет смысл брать (хотя он и может поменяться во время сессии). + записывать в сессию `Useragent` пользователя. При смене `IP` или `Useragent` просите ввести пароль, желательно без потери данных с которыми работает юзер на сайте.

Comment: @Visman если у человека постоянно меняется IP, то ему каждый раз придется вводить пароль - смысл тогда от галочки запомнить? ) Useragent ага, тоже думал брать, только частично, на случай если обновится версия браузера, но это тоже не 100% защита к сожалению )

Comment: Не существует 100% защиты в природе. Все что сделал человек (и не только) можно сломать :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как можно добавить информацию о ПК юзера

Никак.

> каким способом они выводят инфу о моем ПК?

Бeрут её из НТТР заголовка `USER_AGENT`.

> есть проблема - если куку украсть и создать на другом компе куку с таким же названием и содержимым, то без труда происходит авторизация.

Эта проблема существует у любого сайта, использующего куки для авторизации.

> Выслушаю другие варианты реализации функции "Запомнить меня".

Их нет.

Comment: так $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] же хранит инфу только о браузере, как из нее они выводят инфу о моей системе? [http://prntscr.com/8fw2et](http://prntscr.com/8fw2et)

Comment: @Stuf, `Useragent` может содержать информацию в том числе и об ОС.

Comment: @Ипатьев странно, сейчас для теста сделал вывод $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], делал заходы с разных браузеров своих, нигде не было инфы о системе, только о браузере вида Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36

Comment: @Stuf, вас не смущает подстрока `(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)`?

Comment: @Etki да, точно, спасибо )) что-то я и не заметил, в ХР же была другая цифра. с виндой понятно, узнать бы как они определили что я сидел с вебкитовой оперы, а не хрома, как указано в юзерагенте и как они узнали имя компа. ну это ладно, добавлю версию windows  и часть браузера, хотя бы какая та часть инфы о юзере для сравнения